# How to solve `bluez` connection attempts failing with `br-connection-adapter-not-powered`

Tags: linux, bluetooth, bluez

My bluetooth controller appears in `bluetoothctl`:

```
[bluetooth]# list
Controller 08:D8:33:xx:xx:xx BlueZ 5.62 [default]
```

But when I try to connect to a device it gives an error I haven't seen a mention of anywhere:

```
[bluetooth]# connect E8:06:88:xx:xx:xx
Attempting to connect to E8:06:88:xx:xx:xx
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.NotReady br-connection-adapter-not-powered
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, in the version of the distro package of `bluez` I am using, the default configuration is to not automatically use bluetooth controllers after boot. To enable this, uncomment the `AutoEnable` setting in `/etc/bluetooth/main.conf` and set it to `true`:

```
[Policy]
# ... snip ...
AutoEnable=true
```

Then restart `bluez`:

```
sudo service bluez restart
```

or whatever the equivalent is to restart a service on your distro.

(solution as suggested by https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/bluetooth#Auto_power-on_after_boot)

Comment: So, does this solve the problem posed in the question? The question didn't mention automatically connecting.

Comment: My AutoEnable is already set to true, and I still get the error.

Comment: @Brōtsyorfuzthrāx yeah, it did solve it for me; the problem doesn't have anything to do with automatically connecting, it's just about powering on so that when you do manually connect you don't get this power-related error

Comment: Thanks. What solved it for me (I found a solution) was to exit Blueman, if it's open, do the following two commands from the command-line, `sudo systemctl restart bluetooth; blueman-applet`, turn my connecting device off and on, right-click on the Blueman applet, and select `Make Discoverable`; then, right-click on Blueman and go to Devices, right-click on my device, and as soon as my connecting device says `Pairing` (it says that whether it's pairing or not a while after I turn it on), then click connect; it usually connect immediately. Timing of these steps seems to be important.

Comment: My solution doesn't directly use bluez, though.